# how to use ISynchronizeInvoke to communicate with a device?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a finger print scanner and it's SDK (brand : Suprema BioMini usb device).
they have provided some sample C# codes for **windows form** applications.
To initialize device following code segment is used,

```
UFScannerManager ScannerManager;
ScannerManager = new UFScannerManager(this);
```

Here "this" means the current window form object, the  constructor required a "ISynchronizeInvoke sysInvoke" parameter type. So when passing "this" the scanner can be initialized properly in windows form applications. No need to worry about  ISynchronizeInvoke interface.

Now i need to implement a web base program using ASP.Net with c# where i need to communicate with the finger print device. So when initializing how can i create the ScannerManager object by passing ISynchronizeInvoke object??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISynchronizeInvoke` interface is used for controlling sync/async invocation of delegate. Typically, consumer of the interface will do some operation on different thread and then sync-up back on the caller thread passing back the results.

In your case, most probably, `UFScannerManager` is going to make call-back on UI thread of windows form hence it is accepting it as a parameter.

I am not sure what is the use case that you have which compels you to use finger print scanner from a web application. Where the scanner will be attached - on the server machine - correct? So what's the point in controlling it from a remote client machine when some-one has to be physically there in the vicinity of server machine to use it.

Said all that, first thing that you need to ascertain is that if your scanner driver API can work without an UI thread or message pump. If that is possible then you can probably provide your own implementation of `ISynchronizeInvoke` to the API - see here for one such sample implementation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/01/07/isynchronizeinvoke-now.aspx

Most likely, this may not work as it might need UI thread with windows message pump. In case, you need to probably build an windows service that will basically communicate with the scanner API - in the service, you can create a windows form to pass to the API. Windows service can expose WCF interface (say over named pipes) so that ASP.NET application can talk with it to control/read scanner information.